# Cosmo Sql Db - Querying data using continuation tokens never finishes

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

My database has data coming from multiple data sources identified by tenant Id. While One tenant has millions of records, the other has just 75 records like in the screenshot below[image]

When I queried the data using the following code

```
  var count = continuationToken?.Count ?? ContinuationToken.DefaultPageCount;
        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
            MaxItemCount = count,
            RequestContinuation = continuationToken?.NextRowKey
        };

        var query = sortByAscending
            ? _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_collection.DocumentsLink, feedOptions).Where(filter).OrderBy(order).AsDocumentQuery()
            : _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_collection.DocumentsLink, feedOptions).Where(filter).OrderByDescending(order).AsDocumentQuery();

        var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
        var items = feedResponse.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        var nextPageToken = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;

        return new ContinuationTokenData<T>(items, items.Count, nextPageToken, count);
```

with the filter is on the Tenant Id. The data came back for the tenant for the first 2 pages ( 25 records per page) nicely. However, when it got to the last 25 records, the continuation token kept repeating the old value as you can see below
[image]

Do you know how to fix this one or is this a CosmoDb bug? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When token is null it actually means that there's no continuation (as in request 2 and 4).

If you send in FeedOptions RequestContinuation = null it will return first page always.

Comment: The continuation token was set properly and it was a composite value like in the screenshot. The data page returned was not the first page. It alternated between the last page and the second last for the filter criteria. When the first request was issued ( RequestContinuation = null) the first page of data was returned as expected

Comment: Toan, did you find out where's the problem?

Comment: Hi Olga. I have not found out where the issue is. I followed the doc and just extract the continuation token, by somehow Azure just repeats the tokens !

Comment: this part of code seems pretty ok. Can you, pls, post more code where u doing paging cycle and where filter and order variables defined. What indexing policy do you use?